# Move image (which is base64_decode) to folder at server

Tags: php

```
    $store_logo=base64_decode($logo);

    $insert_record="insert into store(store_name,logo,categories,contact,email,pass)values('$store_name','$store_logo','$categories','$contact','$email','$pass')";

    $sql=mysqli_query($con,$insert_record);

    echo "<script>alert('record inserted');</script>";

    $file_path = "store_logo/"; /folder name at server

    $file_path = $file_path.basename($store_logo);

    move_uploaded_file($store_logo,$file_path));
```

i am trying to move the $store_logo image file but some how it didn't get moved to specified folder
please help me out (name of image get successfully inserted in database )

Comment: why would you tag it with android?

Comment: actually image is uploaded from android screen

Comment: but issue is at your server, and has nothing to do with android. IMHO you should remove android tag from this question. It has nothing to with your problem.

Comment: Also, why would you insert a `base64_decode`d image in the DB? Insert the `base64_encode`d image in the DB and the `base64_decode`d in the file system (folder).

Comment: @DroidDev sorry i am new to stack overflow so dont know how it works

Comment: No worries, we are all here to learn. I know you are new, that's why I didn't edited the question myself and told you to do so, so that you know the reason and post a better question/answer next time. If you have time please go through [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) once. It will surely help you to understand stackoverflow model better.

Answer (score 0):

$store_logo contains the contents of the decoded $logo var or only its path?? so why you decode upload path? if $store_logo contains decoded file contents... just save it to destination path. In your code replace move_uploaded_file to file_put_contents($file_path, $store_logo);

I use to move first uploaded files to a temp folder, load it to a variable, decode it and finally save to its destination path. Only assure to move first uploaded files to a temp path because on some servers, PHP don't let to open uploaded files directly from upload folder.

Comment: file_put_contents($file_path, $store_logo); actually i tried this one but its of no use $store_logo is bases64 encoded image n i am decoding it after that i am storing that image name in database after that i have to move that image in folder

Comment: Could you provide me variable name of uploaded file ($_FILES) and I will be able to help you. Why do  you encode a file path? are you sending image from device?

Comment: actully i am trying to upload image which is coming from android device through web service for eg. $sample_logo=base64_encode($_FILES['logo']['name']);

Comment: On your code replace move_uploaded file for: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"], $file_path)); and it should work.